# Can You Help Resolve Issues with Geospatial Unity SDK Placement?

Tags: unity-game-engine, geolocation, anchor, geospatial

Dear StackOverflow Community,

I am reaching out to you for assistance with an issue I am facing with the Geospatial Unity SDK. I am having difficulty placing real-world AR objects in their correct position, and they are always shifting and never in the same location, causing everything to become disordered when I move.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide a solution or any suggestions to overcome this challenge. I have tried searching for a solution online, but I have not been able to find a solution that works for me. Thank you for your time and support.

I look forward to hearing from you.

Best regards,

I attempted to implement the SDK by using the geospatial controller to create an anchor at a specified location and rotation. The "PlaceGeospatialAnchor" function was utilized to create the anchor successfully, and a prefab was then created and attached to the anchor as a child. However, I encountered an issue where the object was not appearing in its intended location, and sometimes shifting when moving.

Comment: Augmented reality is often like this. Usually the best solution is to find a better place to hold the camera, say a table with certain patterns on a differently colored background.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion regarding the challenges of AR deployment. While finding a better place to hold the camera with a patterned table and differently colored background can be a suitable solution for certain applications, my project specifically requires the deployment of AR objects in specific coordinates.

Despite the challenges I have encountered, I am still committed to finding a solution that meets the requirements of my project. I appreciate any additional advice or suggestions you may have that can help me achieve this goal.

Comment: There is usually not much you can do as the programmer in this situation, other than find another AR api. I cannot recommend any, but it is possible that some may be better than others. However, for any specific api, I do not think there is a way to make it “better” by tweaking settings.